# Matching Across Multiple Lines Using Multiline Mode Regex In PL\SQL

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to match across two lines in a multiple line field that is contained in a CLOB. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT MULTI_LINE_TXT,
       REGEXP_COUNT(MULTI_LINE_TXT, '^EVENT TYPE ID: 1$', 1, 'm') AS ID_1_CNT, --Works as expected
       REGEXP_COUNT(MULTI_LINE_TXT, '^EVENT TYPE ID: 1$^Port3$', 1, 'm') AS PORT_3_ID_1_CNT --Does not work how I am hoping
  FROM (SELECT 'EVENT TYPE ID: 1' || CHR(10) || 'Port3' || CHR(10) || 'EVENT TYPE ID: 2' || CHR(10) || 'Port3' || CHR(10) ||
               'EVENT TYPE ID: 1' || CHR(10) || 'Port3' || CHR(10) || 'EVENT TYPE ID: 2' || CHR(10) || 'Port3' || CHR(10) ||
               'EVENT TYPE ID: 1' || CHR(10) || 'Port4' || CHR(10) || 'EVENT TYPE ID: 2' || CHR(10) || 'Port4' AS MULTI_LINE_TXT
          FROM DUAL)
```

Example Output:

```
ROW |   MULTI_LINE_TXT      |   ID_1_CNT    |   PORT_3_ID_1_CNT
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   EVENT TYPE ID: 1    |   3           |   0
    |   Port3               |               |
    |   EVENT TYPE ID: 2    |               |
    |   Port3               |               |
    |   EVENT TYPE ID: 1    |               |
    |   Port3               |               |
    |   EVENT TYPE ID: 2    |               |
    |   Port3               |               |
    |   EVENT TYPE ID: 1    |               |
    |   Port4               |               |
    |   EVENT TYPE ID: 2    |               |
    |   Port4               |               |
```

The first regex that I have:

```
REGEXP_COUNT(MULTI_LINE_TXT, '^EVENT TYPE ID: 1$', 1, 'm') AS ID_1_CNT
```

Counts all of the incidents of `EVENT TYPE ID: 1` as expected. The problem I have is that I do not know which port this event corresponds to unless I also reference the following line.

I tried to reference the next line doing something like this:

```
REGEXP_COUNT(MULTI_LINE_TXT, '^EVENT TYPE ID: 1$^Port3$', 1, 'm') AS PORT_3_ID_1_CNT
```

But as you can see in my Example Output, that does not seem to work the way I am hoping and it always returns a count of 0, when I am expecting a count of 2.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or maybe a different way I could go about trying to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now, don't I feel stupid.... I figured out a solution just a few minutes after I posted this.

Instead of trying to match the end of line `$` and beginning of line `^`, I just matched the new line directly by concatenating it in:

```
REGEXP_COUNT(MULTI_LINE_TXT, '^EVENT TYPE ID: 1' || CHR(10) || 'Port3$', 1, 'm') AS PORT_3_ID_1_CNT
```

When I do this it returns the count of 2 I was hoping for.